# Review First post, Late answer both updating my total edit count for same question

Tags: bug, review

I am not sure if it should actually be a bug, but what I recently noticed was if I open First Post review and Late Answer Review in two different tabs, and refresh both the pages for a new review question/answer, sometimes, I might get a same question/answer on both the tabs. No problems. But if I review both the items, my review count gets incremented by 2 and not by 1. 
Here is a sample
[image]

Comment: Why bug? Those are two different actions. You might also approve suggested edit on that post, that would be third review action on same post. Nothing wrong here in my opinion.

Comment: then its possible to increase my review count by 10 if I open the same thing in 10 tabs.

Comment: No, the key point here is that one is *First Post* review and the other is *Late Answer* review. Two **different** things. If you can review the exact same item in the same queue more than once then it's indeed a bug. :)

Comment: but both showing either a question or an answer.

Comment: You mean the actions look the same? Yeah, it might be better if the review type/queue will appear as well.

Comment: I reviewed same question in `FirstPost` and then in `LateAnswer` in different tabs.

Comment: Not relevant about the tabs. Those are **two different actions**. Sorry I can't make it any more clear.

Comment: Why should reviewing a single item(a question only) twice be considered two different actions?

Comment: @Shadow10YearsWizard I understand the curiosity... Let's say we're reviewing a First Post and open a Late Answer in another tab. If we get the same question and edit one, for the other we just need to refresh and the button "No action needed" gets inactive. If we don't open in a different tab would that still count for both? I understand if it doesn't which then means the best procedure to increase count is to open always both.

Comment: @Tiago maybe back then (when question was asked) it was still possible to perform two different review actions on same post, I didn't check. And bypassing validation by having two tabs is legit, and there might not be server side validation, it's on the bugs "gray zone" - worth reporting, but good chance it's by design. (best example is the ability to answer closed questions few hours after they're closed.)